# Performance AVX-512 vs AutoVectorization on MIC (intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor)

Tags: c, performance, vectorization, intrinsics

I'm struggling with manual vectorization on MIC (intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor), I'm working a simple computation benchmarks (actually benchmarking CPU vs MIC and analyzing the vectorizing effect auto vs manual). I wanted to try the effects of the intrinsics. Here is my problem on the CPU, I can observe a gain of performance of 30% with the m256 intrinsics function (vs the CPU without intrinsics) but on the MIC with the m512 the performance is same than the MIC without the intrinsics (OpenMP + intrinsics), is it normal ?

- MIC+INTR ~ 3.18 sec
- MIC      ~ 3.19 sec
- CPU+INTR ~ 4.31 sec
- CPU      ~ 6.47 sec

The option I used: (intel compiler)

- To compile for MIC + intrinsic: -O3 -openmp -DWITH_INTR -restrict
- To compile for MIC: -O3 -openmp -restrict
- To compile for CPU + intrinsic: -O3 -openmp -DWITH_INTR -no-offload -restrict
- To compile for CPU: -O3 -openmp -no-offload -restrict

My hardware configuration:

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz | SandyBridge (2x8cores | 32 threads)
- MIC: Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) coprocessor x100 family (61 cores | 244 threads)

The code seems long but it is just because there is the calculations without the use of intrinsics and the calculations with 256 bit vector and 512 bit vector.

and the code for whom want to reproduce the results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <offload.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define N 2<<17
#define P 2<<14

__declspec(target(mic:0)) void testVctr( double * restrict a, double * restrict b, double * restrict c )
{

    double t1( omp_get_wtime() );

    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

    __assume_aligned( a, 64 );
    __assume_aligned( b, 64 );
    __assume_aligned( c, 64 );

    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    #ifdef WITH_INTR
        #ifdef __MIC__
            __m512d  n1    = _mm512_set1_pd( 1. );
            __m512d  n1024 = _mm512_set1_pd( 1024. );
            __m512d  n230  = _mm512_set1_pd( 230. );
        #else
            __m256d n1    = _mm256_set1_pd( 1. );
            __m256d n1024 = _mm256_set1_pd( 1024. );
            __m256d n230  = _mm256_set1_pd( 230. );
        #endif
    #endif

    #pragma omp parallel for private( i, j, k ) schedule( dynamic )
    for( i=0; i<N; ++i )
    {
        #ifdef WITH_INTR
            #ifdef __MIC__  
                double * restrict A = (double *restrict) _mm_malloc( (size_t)( (8) * sizeof(double) ), 64 );

                __m512d res   = _mm512_setzero_pd(), r0, r1;

                for( j=0; j<P; j+=8 )
                {
                    r0 = _mm512_load_pd( &b[j] );                   
                    r0 = _mm512_add_pd( r0, n1 );
                    r0 = _mm512_div_pd( n1, r0 );
                    r0 = _mm512_exp_pd( r0 );

                    r1 = _mm512_load_pd( &c[j] );                   
                    r1 = _mm512_mul_pd( r1, n1024 );
                    r1 = _mm512_add_pd( r1, n230 );
                    r1 = _mm512_log_pd( r1 );

                    r0 = _mm512_div_pd( r0, r1 );

                    res = _mm512_add_pd( res, r0 );
                }

                _mm512_store_pd( A, res );

                double tmp(0.);
                for( k=0; k<8; ++k )
                    tmp += A[k];

                a[i] = tmp;

                _mm_free( (double * restrict) A );

            #else
                double * restrict A = (double * restrict) _mm_malloc( (size_t)( (4) * sizeof(double) ), 64 );

                __m256d res   = _mm256_setzero_pd(), r0, r1;

                for( j=0; j<P; j+=4 )
                {
                    r0 = _mm256_load_pd( &b[j] );                   
                    r0 = _mm256_add_pd( r0, n1 );
                    r0 = _mm256_div_pd( n1, r0 );
                    r0 = _mm256_exp_pd( r0 );

                    r1 = _mm256_load_pd( &c[j] );
                    r1 = _mm256_mul_pd( r1, n1024 );
                    r1 = _mm256_add_pd( r1, n230 );
                    r1 = _mm256_log_pd( r1 );

                    r0 = _mm256_div_pd( r0, r1 );

                    res = _mm256_add_pd( res, r0 );
                }

                _mm256_store_pd( A, res );

                double tmp(0.);
                for( k=0; k<4; ++k )
                    tmp += A[k];

                a[i] = tmp;

                _mm_free( (double * restrict) A );

            #endif
        #else
            double res = 0.;

            #pragma simd            
            for( j=0; j<P; ++j )
            {
                double tmp0 = 1./(b[j]+1.);
                double tmp1 = exp( tmp0 );
                double tmp2 = c[j] * 1024;
                double tmp3 = tmp2 + 230;
                double tmp4 = log( tmp3 );
                double tmp5 = tmp1 / tmp4;
                res += tmp5;
            }

            a[i] = res;
        #endif
    }

    printf("\nElapsed time: %f sec\n", omp_get_wtime() - t1 );

}

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    printf("\nOuter loop (N) %d iterations \nInner loop (P) %d iterations\n", N, P );

    double * restrict a = (double * restrict) _mm_malloc( (size_t)( (N) * sizeof(double) ), 64 );
    double * restrict b = (double * restrict) _mm_malloc( (size_t)( (P) * sizeof(double) ), 64 );
    double * restrict c = (double * restrict) _mm_malloc( (size_t)( (P) * sizeof(double) ), 64 ); 

    for( i=0; i<P; ++i )
    {
        b[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;
        c[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }

    #pragma offload target( mic : 0 ) \
    out( a : length( N ) align(512) ) \
    in ( b : length( P ) align(512) ) \
    in ( c : length( P ) align(512) ) 
    testVctr( a, b, c );        

    printf( "\nCheck last result: %f (~ 1.)\n", a[N-1]*2./(P) );

    _mm_free( (double * restrict) a );
    _mm_free( (double * restrict) b );
    _mm_free( (double * restrict) c );

    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps, I missed something in the code or some option in the compilation command.

I'll try any suggestion.

Thank you.

GS

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest slow downs you have is that you are _mm_malloc'ing and then _mm_free'ing in every iteration of the loop.  Heap allocations are incredibly slow.  You would be far better off doing a simple stack allocation, i.e.

```
__declspec( align( 64 ) ) double A[8];
```

This is likely to improve your performance significantly as that dynamic heap management is entirely removed.

That said this is not your main question.  Its quite possible that the intel compiler is vectorising the  loop pretty well.  You should have a look at the assembly that is generated by the compiler and the intrinsics and see whether one is "intrinsically" (sorry) better than the other.  If the intrinsics assembly looks better then its likely that most of the time you are seeing is being taken up by memory accesses ...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try your hint and have a look at the assembly code.

Comment: @user3018144: Does the removing the malloc help?  If so ... I'd be interested to see by how much ...

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't help on my hardware configuration could you test the code with the stack allocation (just on CPU) and tell me. Myabe because the allocation is small ?

Comment: @user3018144: Fair enough the compiler must be optimising the malloc out then.  It is a fixed size malloc so would be easy to optimise out! :)  Unfortunately I don't have the Intel compiler merely MSVC ...